# NetBeans accepting top folder as project folder

Tags: codenameone

Has anyone had success getting NetBeans to accept the top folder of a Codename One Initializr Project as the project folder? Because NetBeans doesn't recognize the folder, I get an error that the pom.xml in the top folder missing, and the javase folder stops the build. Any suggestions?

I will try to integrate the structure Initializr set up into a new NetBeans project to see if I can remove the error.

Comment: Did you select NetBeans as the target when generating the project? Notice the resulting project should include netbeans specific files which you should be able to see in the file manager. Can you include a screenshot or file listing for the root directory?

Comment: Shai, I was able to manually recreate the project. Since I added a textbox, I now hang on a java.lang.nullpointerexception with 27 instances when I try and run the app to the simulator. I submitted the error on the codename one support contact us.

Comment: If you will open a question with the text of the code and the full error message from the logs I can help you with that.

Comment: I asked the question and entered my code and error message. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see it here, was it tagged with Codename One or did you ask it elsewhere? Do you mean [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/16we6yl/javalang_error_message_after_adding_textbox_to_my/)?

Comment: Sorry. I tagged java first, then codenameone. Posted Sat morning right before I added the last comment.